# Need Some Help in Query String in ElasticSearch 6.4.3

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I want to count the number of matching results 
POST /_count 
the following are the bodyJSON

```
{
  "size": "1",
  "from": "0",
  "track_scores": true,
  "sort": [
    {
      "employee_id": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "content",
            "title"
          ],
          "query": "Winter is coming"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "employee_id": {
            "gte": "34222232"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know what the code means in the following code?

```
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "content",
            "title"
          ],
          "query": "Winter is coming"
        }
```

and this one

```
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "employee_id": {
            "gte": "34222232"
          }
        }
      }
```

Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you please format the JSON indentation? It'll make it easier to read your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query helps you find some text in multiple fields. In this case, you're searching for the tokens `Winter is coming` in the `content` and `title` fields.

```
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "content",
        "title"
      ],
      "query": "Winter is coming"
    }
```

The [`range`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) query is a term query that allows you to filter on the value of some field. In this case, you're considering only documents whose `employee_id` field is greater or equal (i.e. `gte`) than `34222232`

```
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "employee_id": {
        "gte": "34222232"
      }
    }
  }
```

Both together mean that you're looking to find documents with `employee_id > 34222232` and whose `title` or `content` fields contain the tokens `Winter is coming`

Comment: Does it means that I am looking for documents that contains tokens Winter is coming in title or content field? or Does it also means that I am looking for documents that contain tokens "Winter", "Is", or "Coming" in the title or content field? Which one is correct from my statements above?

Comment: It's is the same query as `content:Winter OR content:is OR content:coming OR title:Winter OR title:is OR title:coming`, basically any terms is searched in both fields

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you really help me a lot.